# How can we count the number of resources generated by the CloudFormation template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway, aws-sam

I am using Cloudformation and aws-sam. When building/deploying the app, is there any way to count the number of resources being created? For an example, I have a REST API project following serverless architecture, it only has 193 functions under the `Resources` element. But this actually generated 583 resources. I also got to know this because it hit the aws stack resource limit and AWS displayed an error message.

Therefor I am wondering whether there is a way we can know the number of real resources being created.

Below is a sample template I made.

**template.yaml**

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  aws-restapi

  Sample SAM Template for aws-restapi
  
# More info about Globals: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/globals.rst
Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 5
    VpcConfig:
        SecurityGroupIds:
          - sg-041f2xxxd921e8e
        SubnetIds:
          - subnet-03xxxb2d
          - subnet-c4dxxxcb

Resources:

  GetAllAccountingTypesFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    Properties:
      CodeUri: aws-restapi/
      Handler: source/accounting-types/accountingtypes-getall.getallaccountingtypes
      Runtime: nodejs14.x
      Events:
        GetAllAccountingTypesAPIEvent:
          Type: Api # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
          Properties:
            Path: /accountingtypes/getall
            Method: get
            RestApiId:
              Ref: ApiGatewayApi

  GetAccountingTypeByIDFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    Properties:
      CodeUri: aws-restapi/
      Handler: source/accounting-types/accountingtypes-byid.getbyid
      Runtime: nodejs14.x
      Events:
        GetAllAccountingTypesAPIEvent:
          Type: Api # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
          Properties:
            Path: /accountingtypes/getbyid
            Method: get
            RestApiId:
              Ref: ApiGatewayApi
  

  LambdaRole:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::Role'
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - lambda.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - 'sts:AssumeRole'
      Path: /
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: root
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: "2012-10-17"
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces
                  - ec2:CreateNetworkInterface
                  - ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface
                  - ec2:DescribeInstances
                  - ec2:AttachNetworkInterface
                Resource: '*'

Outputs:
  HelloWorldApi:
    Description: "API Gateway endpoint URL for Prod stage for functions"
    Value: !Sub "https://${ServerlessRestApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/Prod/"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the sam CLI to transform the template via `sam validate --debug --template yourtempatefile.yaml` The transformed template is output to stderr along with other debug messages.
This bash oneliner works for me to count the resources.

```
$ sam validate --debug --template mytemplate.yaml 2>&1 | egrep '^    Properties:'  | wc -l
```

Answer (score 0):

Not to my knowledge, but what may help you is this [SAM Serverless Function reference,](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-specification-generated-resources-function.html#sam-specification-generated-resources-function-not-role) which tells you which resources will be generated implicitly when some properties are not specified.

With this in mind you can calculate the amount of resources actually being created.